# Is this a legal way to implement impure virtual functions?

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

By an "impure virtual function", I mean pure virtual functions that also have implementations (as described at http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm) for diagnostic purposes.

The kosher way to implement them is to do:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

void Foo::Bar() { assert(false); }
```

But this is kind of tedious, especially for a class has a number of pure virtual methods.  Also, it's hard to ensure that someone doesn't accidentally add a new pure virtual function without also adding a corresponding implementation.

Ideally what I'd like to do is:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    virtual void Bar() = 0
    {
        assert(false);
    }
};
```

but the C++ standard explicitly disallows this (section 10.4/2 in the ISO C++ 2003 standard).

As an alternative, I've thought of the following hack.  In the `Foo.h` header:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACT_METHOD
#define ABSTRACT_METHOD = 0
#endif

class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    virtual void Bar() ABSTRACT_METHOD;
};
```

and then in the corresponding `Foo.cpp` source file:

```
#define ABSTRACT_METHOD { assert(false); }

#include "Foo.h"

...
```

so that it gets a single compiled implementation.

Would doing so be legal?

Comment: Well, you would have a spurious `;` in the source file...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: True, but is there anything inherently wrong with that?  That's easily avoidable anyway by moving responsibility for the trailing `;` to the macro definition.

Comment: @james: Yes, I believe that would be a compiler error.  I know it's trivially fixable, but this was an incidental observation, not a criticism...

Comment: I assume you meant to include Foo.h before the macro definition as well to enforce the "pure" portion of the class. Once you do that though, you'll get a class type redefinition error.

Comment: @Nick McCowin: No.  The intent is for the "pure" portion of the class to be enforced only for external consumers of `Foo.h`. (But also see my reply to Oli Charlesworth's answer below.)

Comment: In GCC, the default implementation for pure virtual function is something like `assert(false)`.  User doesn't have to do anything for that.  Check docs for your compiler; perhaps, it's the same there?

Comment: @Pavel Shved: Nope, MSVC-built programs just crashes immediately with a "Pure virtual function call" error (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125749), which is kind of annoying to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not legal. The one definition rule says that a class can have multiple definitions in a program (from different translation units), but those definitions must all consist of identical sequences of tokens (3.2/5). `ABSTRACT_METHOD` is a preprocessing token (prior to macro replacement), but that's not good enough.

So your .cpp file can't validly be used in the same program as another .cpp that includes the header.

Comment: Darn, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for pointing me to the relevant section of the standard.  I suppose that means that `__declspec(dllimport)` vs. `__declspec(dllexport)` attributions technically aren't legal from a standards standpoint either.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Technically yes, `__declspec` is a reserved name, so as far as the standard is concerned a program containing it is not strictly conforming. The program can still be valid in the dialect of C++ defined by Microsoft, though, and if that documentation relaxes the ODR (explicitly or by implication), then you're fine.

Comment: Perhaps a middle ground would be to let `ABSTRACT_METHOD` be different things in internal development builds (to let the compiler catch incomplete derived classes) but to let it be the stub implementation everywhere else.

Comment: @jamesdlin: or do one automated build with it as `=0;`, solely for the purpose of checking that it compiles, but as the function body in both development and release. If the assert is going to be triggered, you'd probably prefer to trigger it in the build that you're using to develop, to catch it as early as possible and hopefully as close to the bug as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer whether it's valid or not.  But if the user of your class declares a derived class in the source file, the compiler won't enforce that `Bar()` must be implemented in that derived class (because it won't see the `= 0`).  I would imagine that this alone would be a reason not to do it like this.

Comment: That's a fair point.  It's not an issue for our codebase since we usually separate classes into separate files.  Another approach would be to have a single, separate source `impureVirtualStubs.cpp` file that defines the implementation version of the macro, includes the various abstract base class headers, and does nothing else.